# How to synchronise JSON data with changes from DOM events (drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a Vue component that I use to render child components based on some JSON data. I would like the user to be able to move and add components by dragging and dropping DOM elements on the page (using a plugin like jQuery draggable, droppable and Sortable).

However upon every 'move' action I need to synchronise back the changes to the JSON so that Vue can re-render the components so that it represents the new state.

My problem is that I don't know how to communicate the old and new position of the targeted DOM element to the JSON. They don't have any relationship.

This is the JSON of a single node inside the data function. Every node is passed to the render function to render a DOM element.

```
{
 tagName: 'div',
 textNode: 'This is some text.',
 props: {
   class: '.blabla-class'
 },
 children: []
}
```

**I came up with two possible ways to achieve this:**

1. Whenever the user completes a drag and drop action I get the
   corresponding DOM elements from the event, and I walk up the DOM
   tree using a recursive function to create some kind of map of where
   this DOM element was and where it should be.

   The output this function would be an array: for example [0, 2, 5,
   6].

   This array basically tells me how to access the JSON object. In this
   example that would be: JSON[0].children[2].children[5].children[6].

   To me, this feels kind of an arbitrary way of representing the
   position of a DOM element. There should be a more elegant way.
2. The second possibility would be to assign a unique ID to every JSON object and its corresponding DOM element. And then on every move action I would search through the whole JSON tree to find the object with a particular ID, and change its position based on some anchor (for example append after another ID). This is doable, but I'm worried about the performance of doing a full recursive search through a JSON tree that could contain 1000+ nodes. Will it be fast enough (< 50 ms)?

I'm very curious how you guys would solve this challenge!

Comment: Can you paste the code? It is less ambiguous than a textual description.

Comment: @acdcjunior I've pasted the example JSON for one element.

Comment: I am not sure if this fits your particular use case but you could always try the Vue port of Sortable.js https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple, you can just use the native HTML5 drag and drop API. Make an element draggable with `draggable="true"` and use `@drop` and `@dragstart` just like you would use the `@click` handler. I don't know exactly how your data is structured since your question unfortunatly did not include any code but you can just use the `dataTransfer.setData()` and `dataTransfer.getData()` functions that come with these events. Remember Vue.js is data-driven in nature so try to avoid touching the DOM, it's a slippery slope of untraceable bugs and unpredictable user experience from there on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe it wasn't clear from my question, but I don't have any problem integrating drag and drop functionality itself. It's just that I don't know how to synchronise back the changes to my JSON.

An example:
1. I render Vue components on the page based on the JSON.
2. The user moves DOM element from position A to position B somewhere else in the tree.
3. I know the position of the DOM element, but I don't know which (nested) JSON object belongs to this particular element! My problem: How do I link those two together?

Comment: @NvdB31 Couldn't you use the `getData()` and `setData()` methods for this? Then find the node in the original JSON using `.find()` for example (or use an object and do it by key) and add it/delete it?